# Few shell commands doesn't work when I Invoke a script via QProcess in Qt

Tags: linux, qt

Hi I have a shell script which executes some commands, when I invoke that script using terminal it works fine but when I invoke the script using a QProess few commands doesn't works well.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Invoking the script"
euid=$1
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
echo "Arguments missing"
      exit 1
fi

echo "arg 1: $1"
data=$1;
name=$(echo $data | cut -b 1-7)
age= $(echo $data | cut -b  10-11)
echo "$name"
echo "$age"
```

Here is the way I use QProcess

```
// Environment setup
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
candidateProcess->setProcessEnvironment(env);
QString script("/home/root/scripts/getInfo.sh");
candidateProcess->start("/bin/bash", QStringList() << script << qwertyuand21");
```

If I run this script in shell It works fine, get the value of name and age. But when I invoke the script from Qt using the above stated method I get error for cut command, First 3 echo works well, then I get error for the cut command as `cut : command not found` and then nothing comes up for the echo commands because cut command failed.
What is the reason for that? I have provided shell for the process but still these errors??

Comment: It looks like the `QProcess` is running with a wrong or incomplete environment -- specifically the `PATH` variable.  Try doing [`Process->setProcessEnvironment(QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment())`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProcessEnvironment) before invoking `QProcess::start`.  Note: it would be more helpful if you showed the *real* code you're using to create/start the `QProcess`.

Comment: This is the real code,

Comment: Then you're not supplying enough arguments to the script and it will exit before it even gets to the point of invoking `cut` -- right?

Comment: I added this 
  `// Environment setup
    QProcessEnvironment env =QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
    candidateProcess->setProcessEnvironment(env);`
But still same error.

Comment: @G.M is there any other way?

Comment: Supply the absolute path to `cut` IE `/usr/bin/cut` in your script or fix the PATH in your script to explicitly add `/usr/bin` to your PATH. Chances are, PATH is getting wiped out by Qt and your script is searching for `cut` in the `pwd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `sh` command and some test arguments

```
QString script("/home/root/scripts/getInfo.sh arguments123456");
Process->start("/bin/sh ", QStringList() << script");
```