# QProcess fails to execute a terminal line command via QPushButton

Tags: c++, bash, qt, qt5, qprocess

I am trying to execute a command line using `QProcess` as soon as I push a `QPushButton` on my gui.
**The problem** I have is that the `.sh` executable file is never executed.

The script I am trying to execute is very simple and reported below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "try one two three"
rostopic echo -b LaserScan_PointCloud2_test.bag -p /scan > laserScan_test_1.csv
```

Below the function that activate the button:

**filterpcdinterface.h**

```
private slots:
    void on_executeScriptBtn_clicked();
private:
    QProcess *executeBash;
```

**filterpcdinterface.cpp**

```
FilterPCDInterface::FilterPCDInterface(QNode *node, QWidget *parent) :
    qnode(node), 
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FilterPCDInterface)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    executeBash = new QProcess;
    executeBash->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    connect(executeBash, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [this] {
    qDebug() << "This is the output from the process: ";
      on_executeScriptBtn_clicked();
    });
}


void FilterPCDInterface::on_executeScriptBtn_clicked()
{
  executeBash->waitForFinished();
  QString script("/home/emanuele/Desktop/bags/test.sh");
  executeBash->start("sh",QStringList() << script);

  if(!executeBash->waitForStarted()) //default wait time 30 sec
      qWarning() << " cannot start process ";

  int waitTime = 60000 ; //60 sec
  if (!executeBash->waitForFinished(waitTime))
           qWarning() << "timeout .. ";

  executeBash->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
  QString str(executeBash->readAllStandardOutput());
}
```

So far I have been consulting several posts but none of them helpd me solve the problem.
I came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064474/few-shell-commands-doesnt-work-when-i-invoke-a-script-via-qprocess-in-qt) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086771/how-to-start-a-shell-script-with-qprocess) from which I actually got the idea.

As interpreter I tried both `"/bin/sh"` and `"sh"` but none of them gave the expected result.
To be precise I tried both this one:

```
  executeBash->start("sh",QStringList() << script);
```

and

```
  executeBash->start("/bin/sh",QStringList() << script);
```

But nothing happened.

I finally came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407394/qt-run-shell-commands-via-qprocess) very useful post which actually helped me set up the whole button function, but when it was time to execute the script nothing happens this time too.

I am not sure if this strange behavior is caused by the `connect` function in the constructor. The problem is also that the `qDebug()` statement is also never reached.

The [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached) mention the possibility to use a `startDetached` statement but I am not sure it can fully relate to what I am trying to achieve.
Always the official documentation reports the following statement [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached)

> Unix: The started process will run in its own session and act like a
>   daemon.

And therefore I thought that there was a process session working and that could be executed but it is not.

In conclusion: I have been researching a lot what the problem might be but I keep missing something I don't see. Please point to the right direction to help solving this issue is anyone happened to have the same problem.

Comment: How do you know that the script is not executed ? Because it is normal if the standard output is empty

Comment: Hello @thibsc and thanks for reading the question. I know it because the statement `qDebug() << "This is the output from the process: "` is never shown on terminal. Therefore the execution of the file does not happen, and I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe it is normal because you redirect the ouput in a file, try to just put an echo in your script and see if it still nothing happen

Comment: Ok, I tried it and updated the question. Basically I added `echo "try one two three"` on the bash file but still nothing happens

Comment: You read the standard output at the end of your `on_executeScriptBtn_clicked()` you print the content of your `str` var to see if it contains something ?

Comment: Recommend moving the `executeBash->setProcessChannelMode` into the constructor right after the instance of `executeBash` is created (if you do want to see `stderr`). The 1st time `on_executeScriptBtn_clicked` is called, the channels are _not_ merged so stderr won't be picked up by `QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput`.

Comment: @thibsc, print ing the `str` at the end of the statement I didnt try. However I have a small problem, I can't `return str` because the function is `void FilterPCDInterface::on_executeScriptBtn_clicked()`, how can I bypass this problem and try your suggestion?

Comment: Do not use designer to create your slot, make the connections by yourself. With your own slot you can do what you want. And just use `qDebug()` to see the content. And take in consideration what Linville said

Comment: Guys something is happening. I implemented @Linville and got [this](https://i.imgur.com/SdXhZb0.png), however the `.sh` file is still not executed. I updated the code in the question.

Comment: Do you see something I don't see?

Comment: Remove your 2 last line of your `on_executeScriptBtn_clicked()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**header:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QProcess>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_executeScriptBtn_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QProcess    * executeBash;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**source:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->executeBash = new QProcess(this);
    this->executeBash->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    connect(this->executeBash, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [script = this->executeBash](){
        qDebug() << "[EXEC] DATA: " << script->readAll();
    });
    connect(this->executeBash, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
          [script = this->executeBash](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
        qDebug() << "[EXEC] FINISHED: " << exitCode << exitStatus;
        if(script->bytesAvailable() > 0)qDebug() << "[EXEC] buffered DATA:" << script->readAll();
    });
    connect(this->executeBash, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [script = this->executeBash](QProcess::ProcessError error){
        qDebug() << "[EXEC] error on execution: " << error << script->errorString();
    });

}
void MainWindow::on_executeScriptBtn_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "Button clicked!"; // if you don't see this message check your SIGNAL/SLOT connections!
    //this->executeBash->execute(...) // <- will wait till script is finished and block main thread
    this->executeBash->start(QStringLiteral("/bin/sh"), QStringList() << QStringLiteral("/home/emanuele/Desktop/bags/test.sh")); //will start new process without blocking
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){delete ui;}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you very much that works great! I have a question though, on the `on_executeScriptBtn_clicked()` you left `//this->executeBash->execute(...)` commented and was wondering its use and if I need to use it? Thank you very much for your time! :) Very much appreciated

Comment: @Emanuele, if you need to wait till your script is finished execution and only then execute next steps in your code you could use **execute** function of QProcess instead of **start**. execute function will block your "code" until the script is finished(your GUI will be unresponsive in this time) sometimes usefull in console apps, but for GUI apps better to use **start** function of QProcess, **start** will execute asynchronous(not blocking your GUI). I just commented it for you if you need this kind of behavior :)